# Adding in hidden input types changes my css

Tags: python, html

My code looks like this:

```
<form name="deleteUser" action="/groupmanager" method="post"><div id="x">  {% csrf_token %} 
<input type="hidden" name="username" value = "{{name}}"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="groupName" value = "{{group}}"></input>
<input type="submit" name="xButton" id="xButton" value="x"></div></form>
```

And the code works exactly the way I want it to but now that I've added it, the layout of the page has changed. Now the button has moved onto a new line instead of being on the same line as the things before it in the code.

My code used to look like this:

```
<div id="x"><input type="submit" name="xButton" id="xButton" value="x"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleave the change is in IE only ? Try adding `position:relative; float:left` to the css of hidden inputs.

Comment: Try to debug by adding the following css to all of the new tags You added : display:none; width:0px; height:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; . Try to determine, which tag makes the difference - maybe it is the form itself ?

Comment: Curly braces (e.g. '{' and '}') are block delimiters for CSS.  Is it necessary to use those characters in your form values?

Comment: Yeah I need the curly braces because I'm also working in django.